# Linux sleep timer + cancel timer + locked screen on wake-up

Tags: linux, bash, timer

If I use `sudo bash -c "sleep 15m; pm-suspend"`

I want to be able to

1. Cancel the sleep timer
2. See my screen in "locked state" on wake-up, if the command executes

How can I accomplish 1 and 2 (gui suspend gives me a locked-screen on wake-up)?

**Note** - A different command which can create a sleep timer + cancellation and provide locked screen on wake-up is also fine!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using (in terminal) - 
 
`sleep 15m; dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.login1" /org/freedesktop/login1 org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Suspend boolean:true`

15m is the time - 15 minutes, we can change it; s (seconds) and h (hours) can also be used.

No other command should be used in the same terminal, otherwise timer cannot be cancelled!

To cancel the timer, we can simply use `Ctrl + c in the same terminal` before 15 minutes (or whatever time has been set) have elapsed.

It does result in "lock" screen on wake up!